# not able to insert values in my postgresql database

Tags: java, postgresql

In java code:

```
CallableStatement cs=null;
int bcode=1;
int dcode=3;
int noftab=3;
String sql2 = "{? = call public.insertdepttables('"+bcode+"','"+dcode+"','"+noftab+"')}";
cs = conn.prepareCall(sql2);
cs.registerOutParameter(1,Types.INTEGER);
rset1=cs.getInt(1);
system.out.println("success="+rest1);
```

In insertdepttables:(Function in my db-postgresql)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.insertdepttables
(
  IN  branch_code  integer,
  IN  dept_code    integer,
  IN  no_tables    integer
)
RETURNS integer AS
$$
DECLARE
count integer;
begin
     IF no_tables>0 THEN     
     LOOP
     insert into t_dept_tables(branch_code,dept_code,table_no)values(branch_code,dept_code,no_tables);

     no_tables=no_tables-1; 
     Count=count+1;
     EXIT when no_tables =0;
     END LOOP ;
     END IF;
RETURN count;
end
$$
```

actually i need to insert the no_table (i.e.,3) times row in my t_dept_tables in postgresql. So wat i have done is i hav written functions in database. I need to call it from java code. So I used callable stmt there:

My output should be like this in db:

```
bcode dcode table_no
1      3     1
1      3     2
1      3     3
```

Now while executing java code,
I'm getting the result as,

console:

```
success=3
```

but 3 rows arent inserted in db, but while executing the function in my db, the values get inserted. So no wrong in my db function. please help me to sort this out.

Comment: are you missing a transaction and a commit?

Comment: Why do you use a loop (and a function) in the first place? This could be done with one simple insert statement?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name wanted to mention this, but anyway it's interesting why OP table is not updated

Comment: @RomanPekar: I would guess it's a missing `commit()` as user2310289 suggested (or the Java code is connecting to a different database)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name may be add this as an suggestion/answer?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you haven't forgot to actually call statement, like:

```
cs.executeQuery();
...
cs.close();
```

BTW, your task could be achieved without functions, like (don't use string concatenation, use parameter values):

```
String stm = "insert into t_dept_tables(branch_code,dept_code,table_no) values(branch_code,dept_code,no_tables); VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
cs = con.prepareStatement(stm);
cs.setInt(1, id);
cs.setInt(3, id);
cs.setInt(3, id);
rs = cs.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Ya given cs.close(); but its not working..  pl help me to sort out

Comment: I don't see execute in your code, please provide you actual code

Comment: int bcode=1;
int dcode=3;
int noftab=3;
String sql2 = "{? = call public.insertdepttables('"+bcode+"','"+dcode+"','"+noftab+"')}";
 cs = conn.prepareCall(sql2);

 cs.registerOutParameter(1,Types.INTEGER);
 

 cs.execute();
 rset1=cs.getInt(1);


 
 System.out.println("hiii success"+rset1);

 cs.close();